# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function (in AJAX callback)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am trying to update a FullCalendar object using a function that receives an array of events.

```
$('#sh1_cal').fullCalendar({

    events: function(callback) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/getEvents',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(reply) {

                //var events = [];
                console.log("printing " + reply.first)
                alert(typeof reply.first);
                callback(reply.first);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Reply is intended to be an object containing two arrays as its properties. I'm extracting the first, and it seems that the typeof alert is returning the correct type, but the callback is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: you have a `;` missing on the console.log line.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the issue persists.

Comment: Whats the callback you pass in>?

Comment: `reply.first` is of what type?

Comment: I'm not passing anything in, this is just the way it was done in an example on the FullCalendar documentation. I assumed the object passes something in for you.

Comment: `reply.first` returns object type.

Comment: are you missing this line? `<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar.js'></script>`

Comment: To me, it looks like `callback` isn't a function. Which would indicate that whatever example you took this from is outdated, or you're using an outdated version of the plugin.

Comment: You should run a `console.log(typeof callback)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this plugin but from the docs (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/) it looks like the events function takes 3 parameters: start, end, and callback.

Start and end are date objects indicating when the event starts and ends. The way you have it now, that function thinks there is a date object called 'callback' which is why you're getting the error. In JavaScript the name of the parameter is not important (for example you can call it 'cb' or 'foo' instead of 'callback') but the order is.

Try (untested):

```
$('#sh1_cal').fullCalendar({

    events: function(start, end, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/getEvents',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(reply) {
                callback(reply.first);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed it! However, the events don't still load, so I'm not sure if I'm now closer or further from the solution

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Sorry I don't know anything about the plugin so I can't say what's going on with the events :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#sh1_cal').fullCalendar({
    events: 'http://localhost:8080/getEvents'
});
```

Shouldn't be any need for writing your own ajax call, it's built in.

If that doesn't work, can you post the output of your JSON feed?

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know if it works:

```
$('#sh1_cal').fullCalendar({

    events: function(cb) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/getEvents',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(reply) {
               return cb(reply.first);
               //or try:  cb(reply.first);

            }
        });
    }(callback)
});
```

if not that, remove the return on the callback.

did either work?

*please note: I assume that "callback" is a function you are passing in and have instantiated it somewhere.

Comment: still getting error after applying your solution in full calendar version - 4. Error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Event (As Function) in fullcalendar has been changed. Now the third parameter is timezone. 
Further information on [FullCalendar Documentation v2](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/)